# Build Docker image on tmpfs

Tags: linux, docker, tmpfs

I have a Dockerfile that change file permissions to various folders, one of that is a `node_modules`

```
RUN chown -R 0:0 .                                                                                                                                                   
RUN chmod a+rX -R -c .
```

And this takes time!

I was wondering if I could use a `tmpfs` partition to build, and instruct docker to use it, because I have a lot of RAM, and RAM is fast.

Is it possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community the idea in question is simple: use tmpfs for all image building to speed things up but to save the final image as usual. I have the same question